# Vertical ListView of Horizontal Listviews

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I am trying to have a vertical list of horizontal listviews. Currently the User Experience is really bad in that scrolling does sometimes not work. This is similar to like a youtube homepage or Spotify where you scroll down and each row is scrollable

```
 Expanded(
                  flex: 5,
                  
                
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 500,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: skills.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index){
                      return CategoryHomeScreen(videosInSection: videoRecommended[skills[index]] ?? [], skill: skills[index]);
                    }),
                  ),
                ),
```

The widget referred to in item builder

```
return Column(
  children: [
    Padding(
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(HomeBrain.headingPaddingLeftSide, 0, 0, 0),
        child: Text(
          widget.skill,
          style: Constants.subHeading,
        )),
  
    //these are horizontal scrollviews to see more videos
    Container(
      height: HomeBrain.videoHeightBox +
          HomeBrain.sizeBetweenvideoAndSub +
          HomeBrain.videoHeight -
          HomeBrain.takeAwayFromContainerSizedOfVideoFram,
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 0,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ListView.builder(
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: widget.videosInSection.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
            //passes over author, thumbnail url, thumbnail and video url so each tile is unique
            return ScreenTile(
              authorName: widget.videosInSection[index].userNameBy,
              pathToThumbnail: widget.videosInSection[index].thumbNailUrl,
              thumbnail: widget.videosInSection[index].thumbnail,
              pathToVideo: widget.videosInSection[index].videoUrl,
              profilePic: widget.videosInSection[index].profilePic,
              videoBrain: widget.videosInSection[index],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: you want to scroll your list horizontally?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I want a vertical list view to have children of horizontal scrolling lists.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way. This is for demo purposes.

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 15,
    itemBuilder: (_, i) {
      return _horizontalListView();
    },
  ),

Widget _horizontalListView() {
return SizedBox(
  height: 120,
  child: ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemBuilder: (_, __) => _buildBox(color: Colors.orange),
  ),
);
Widget _buildBox({required Color color}) => Container(margin: EdgeInsets.all(12), height: 100, width: 200, color: color);
```